# Pass parameters between method name

Tags: methods, language-agnostic, parameter-passing

I was wondering if you know of any programming language in which we can pass parameters inside method name. I'm guessing this could improve the code readability. I.e.
Lets say I want to multiply to integers in a method. Normally my method declaration would be something like:

```
function multiply(int a, int b){
    return a*b;
}
```

However, it may be nice to be able to define it this way also:

```
function multiply (int a) times (int b){
    return a*b;
}
```

This way, we could make a more explicit call in the code by calling:

```
var c = multiply(4)times(2);
```

This could have a greater impact on more complicated code and programming syntax.
Do you know if something like this exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, there is Smalltalk which is really expressive with its keyword messages...

```
n := collection size // 2.
head := collection copyFrom: 1 to: n.
```

Other than that, you will find that in ADA or Python, and probably some others you can prefix each argument with a key (which should match the function parameter names)...